# Some slides not working in Firefox - Wordpress Revolution Slider

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

Currently working on the website [realinstitute.com.au](http://realinstitute.com.au/) and if you view it in Firefox you'll see that the first 3 slides aren't working. Works perfectly fine in other browsers including IE, it's just Firefox.

I've noticed that it's only happening on slides where some of the elements are outside the boundaries, but I've tried altering that and it seemed to have no effect, but I feel it might be related.

Any suggestions? Really lost on this one, I'd usually be more helpful in my questions sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the path of your first image :

`<img src="http://realinstitute.com.au\/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/hero-bg.png" />`

Notice the wrong path ?

Try:

`<img src="http://realinstitute.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/hero-bg.png" />`

Comment: All working now, you can check it out if you like. You've just helped me finish off the project completely. Thank you :)

Comment: I checked it when I inspected it :)
Glad to help :)